# :before pseudo element not displaying image on input element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I would like an image to appear before the text "Comment" but still inside the button. Is it possible to do something like that?

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/yGk9Z/

html

```
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Comment">
```

css

```
input[type=submit]:before {
    content: url("comment.png"); }
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You cannot use the `:before` on an `input`. See [the information on pseudo-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info).

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as background image:

```
input[type=submit] {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/X1UMz.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: @bskool: You have a `:before` left in the selector. Remove that.

Comment: Ah yes, but the problem with that is that I already have a background gradient: http://pastebin.com/B3LgziTY

Comment: @bskool: Specify the `background-image` and `background-repeat` styles instead of overwriting everything by specifying just `background`.

Comment: @bskool: When you specify both `background` and specific background properties, you need to specify the specific properties after: http://jsfiddle.net/yGk9Z/5/ Sadly, however, it seems that the background image removes the gradient...

Comment: Yea:/ Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @bskool: I tested in it in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, and they all react differently. Opera won't show the gradient at all, so you would have to resort to something more robust to make it work in all browsers anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a button instead:

```
<button>Comment</button>​

button:before{content: url("http://i.imgur.com/X1UMz.png")};
```

Comment: Although this would be a solution, it's not an option. It would take quite a bit of work to convert them all to buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `background-image` and a left `padding` instead:

```
input[type=submit]{
   background: #fff url(comment.png) no-repeat left center;
   padding-left: 32px; /* insert your actual img-width + some pixel space */
}
```

Comment: Basically what Guffa said above, though this won't work, I already have background gradients set.

Comment: @bskool: Oh, I see, Guffa posted his answer 3 seconds earlier and I didn't pay attention. You should probably include the gradient to your question.